# How to get the Active tool or change the active tool to the "Selection Tool"?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am just getting started on learning ExtendScript or general scripting for Adobe programs. So pardon me, if I am of base.

I think I have figured out most of what I need to know but I am stuck on wrapping my head around this **Object Model** diagram:

[image]

I want to get what the active tool (in the toolbar panel) is, so I can conditionally react to it. But where is such a property as the "Active Tool" stored in the above tree, or is such as feature even supported?

For example, I can successfully retrieve the name of the active document with:

```
var docSelected = app.activeDocument;
alert(docSelected);
```

I want to do a similar thing with the active tool:

```
//Pseudo code
var currentToolIs = //Some Object here
If (CurrentToolIs == "SelectionTool")
    //Activate Direct Selection Tool
Else    
    alert("Doing  Something Else...")
```

[THIS](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/q-is-there-way-to-get-current-tool-selected-in-tool-panel/td-p/9018195) same question was asked at the Adobe forums, but they never got an answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I`m not sure there is an object for the tools. Is there a reason you want to change the active tool?

Comment: There is the almost correct answer on the Adobe forum: "Unfortunately, You can't get tools using Extendscript." Actually you can _set_ a tool in Extendscript in InDesign. But not in Illustrator, as far as I know.

Comment: @YuriKhristich I completely over looked that answer. Thank you for brining it to my attention!

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Just to create a toggle hotkey within my system. I will relegate this to AutoHotkey then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know you can do it in InDesign using:

```
var item = app.toolBoxTools.currentTool;
alert(item);
```

It will return the tool currently selected such as PEN_TOOL or TYPE_TOOL as an object.

I can't guarantee it will work on all the Adobe apps.